# What is a .git.dmp file and how can I use it?

Tags: git

I just backed up my unfuddle account and it sent a zip file with my git repositories as a .git.dmp file.  Do I just remove the .dmp ending and use it like a normal .git repository?

Comment: If you are in *nix, please run the "file" command against your dump file and let us know what file reports.  Although this is not really a programming question.

Comment: Try using this script I made based on @Rob's answer: https://gist.github.com/drkvogel/fd0580cab0bf7019948d9bad229143d2

Comment: using file command on ".git.dmp" sadly only results in "data" not helping much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it is possibly a git bundle. If that's the case, you can simply clone it to a new directory:

```
git clone whatever.git.dmp whatever
```

Comment: Does not work with unfuddle dmp files. (At least, the one I tried.) Rob's answer using fast-import did work.

Comment: Doesn't work. Rob's answer does work.

Answer (score 17):

[This blog post](http://trevoro.ca/blog/2010/02/12/unfuddle-git-backups-how-to-actually-use-them/) has a good explanation of using Git and Unfuddle. In short, it says to:

```
mkdir reponame
cd reponame
git init
git fast-import < ../my-unfuddle-backup.git.dmp
git checkout master
```

Comment: A bit more details in this post of mine http://blog.riff.org/2016_10_22_tip_of_the_day_unfuddle_dmp_format_and_lesserknown_git_commands

Comment: @Bogdan fixed: `&lt;` changed to `<`, it should work now (works for me)

Comment: p.s. I created a command to do this, in case you have a lot of .dmp files (like I do after a certain git hosting site terminated their free plan): https://gist.github.com/drkvogel/fd0580cab0bf7019948d9bad229143d2

Comment: use   "for data in *.git.dmp ; do undump.sh $data ;done"   for @drkvogel s script if script was saved as undump.sh and is in your path to loop through all you .git.dmp files. Thank you unfuddle for 0 documentation

Comment: Thanks @drkvogel and CaptainCrunch - I'm (sinking) in the same Unfuddle boat as you. Loooong time user, they just closed my account without warning. Luckily, they sent me this backup file, with dozens of dmp. While this script will help, I still wonder what to do with my svn.dmp files (yes, that's how long I was a loyal user ).

Comment: @CaptainCrunch: would add 2 details to your code: 1. make sure you `chmod +x undmp.sh` 2. add local path: `for data in *.git.dmp ; do ./undump.sh $data ;done`.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy figured it out for SVN: `svnadmin create repo_name` and then `svnadmin load repo_name < repo_name.svn.dmp`

Comment: @Peterdk tried following your advice, got this: `svnadmin: E000013: Can't move 'repo_name/db/revprops/0/svn-hLIiul' to 'repo_name/db/revprops/0/0': Permission denied`. Adding `sudo` didn't solve it - not sure it's a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a git internal bundle there's also just:

```
git bundle verify filename.git.dmp
```

command. No need to try to clone it